# Null URL in JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect with mysql with Java.
I am using db.properties files to get the connection details.

I am kind of new guy to work with the db.properties file. What is the wrong with my code??

It is as below

```
#mysql DB properties
#DB_DRIVER_CLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/ci_intro
#DB_USERNAME=root
#DB_PASSWORD=
```

My Java Class file is

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JDBCExample {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    System.out
            .println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("db.properties");
    props.load(in);
    in.close();

    String driver = props.getProperty("DB_DRIVER_CLASS");
    if (driver != null) {
        Class.forName(driver);
    }

    String url = props.getProperty("DB_URL");
    String username = props.getProperty("DB_USERNAME");
    String password = props.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    if (con != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting below error

```
-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.avn.notificationengine.JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:33)
```

Comment: Did you debug the values you're getting from properties file?

Comment: I think your `props` object is empty or getting nothing with `getProperty()`. Try prinitng out them.

Comment: Your property file is commented out. Uncomment the db related properties and it should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "`#`" in your `*.properties` file. All that follows "`#`" is comment. Your `*.properties` should be:

```
#mysql DB properties
DB_DRIVER_CLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/ci_intro
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```